# How can I install Wifi-drivers in fedora? I have just '…exe' files

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, asus-laptop

Wifi connect field is so small later than install fedora 26. Can wifi-driver provide to me larger wifi field? (laptop: asus: k55vj)

Comment: ok I know but linux drivers does not exist on asus website then how can i find that drivers for linux?

Comment: Exes are for windows. So no, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone this `git` repo by running this codes on your terminal that's if you already have git installed, and kick of the automatic install script:

```
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver.git && cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver && ./install.s
```

I don't really know more about your hardware, but if any further error occurs in the cause of the installation, you can check [Wifi Drivers](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver)

Comment: Thanks that is great !!! (I am new in here so i cant vote your answer. Sorry about that :(

Comment: has it resolved your driver issue fully?

Comment: I hope so it works for now :D

Comment: then you can accept the answer by clicking on an accept sign directly on the left hand side of the answer so that it might help someone who might have you same kinda issue. @kira

Comment: i said i dont have 15 reputation so cant vote sorry again :( @Antz

Comment: @kira, you can still click the checkmark icon to mark this as the answer. You can do that on any question you post, regardless of your points. Please do so if Antz resolved your issue.

Comment: k i did ty again